# ViewportRectの参照

Tags: c#, unity3d

題の通り、CameraのViewportRectの値をC#Script内で変更したいのですが、
如何すればよいのでしょうか。
ご教授お願いします。

Comment: 表題が「ViewportRectの参照」となっていますが、参照ではなく変更したいんですよね。

Answer (score 0):

Unity 4.x で試したところ下記の方法で設定可能でした。

```
var camera = 何かしらの方法でCameraを取得
camera.rect = new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```